# Generating C# code from XML Changed Structure

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2022, codegen

I have a C# console application using .NET 6.0 and am generating my data structure code from XML. The application loads a configuration xml file at runtime and uses to data in it configure itself. I am developing this in Visual Studio 2022 using the paste xml as classes function to generate my code.

This has been fine so far, with the data structure having been tweaked several times so far. However, Visual studio has changes how its generating some of the code and it is breaking my application despite me having made no changes to this part of the data structure. Below is a snippet of the XML, the Event tag is a list of events that are loaded into the application.

```
<Event>
  <EventDetails>
    <Name>Fire Spiral</Name>
    <Source>Twitch</Source>
    <Type>Twitch_Bits</Type>
    <ID>Twitch_Bits_ID_1</ID>
  </EventDetails>
  <EventTarget>
    <Target>OBS</Target>
    <Goal>OBS_Enable_Source</Goal>
    <Args>
      <Arg>
        <Key>Source</Key>
        <Value>Fire Spiral - Media Source</Value>
      </Arg>
      <Arg>
        <Key>BitsAmount</Key>
        <Value>1</Value>
      </Arg>
    </Args>
        <Callback>
      <EventID>Bits_Callback_ID_1</EventID>
      <Delay>0</Delay>
    </Callback>
    <Duration>10</Duration>
  </EventTarget>
</Event>
<Event>
  <EventDetails>
    <Name>Arrow Volley</Name>
    <Source>Twitch</Source>
    <Type>Twitch_Bits</Type>
    <ID>Twitch_Bits_ID_2</ID>
  </EventDetails>
  <EventTarget>
    <Target>OBS</Target>
    <Goal>OBS_Enable_Source</Goal>
    <Args>
      <Arg>
        <Key>Source</Key>
        <Value>Arrow Volley - Media Source</Value>
      </Arg>
      <Arg>
        <Key>BitsAmount</Key>
        <Value>100</Value>
      </Arg>
    </Args>
        <Callback>
      <EventID>Bits_Callback_ID_2</EventID>
      <Delay>0</Delay>
    </Callback>
    <Duration>10</Duration>
  </EventTarget>
</Event>
```

Before hand, it was generating the code below:

```
    /// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEvent
{

    private ConfigEventEventDetails eventDetailsField;

    private ConfigEventEventTarget eventTargetField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ConfigEventEventDetails EventDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventDetailsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventDetailsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ConfigEventEventTarget EventTarget
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventTargetField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventTargetField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEventEventDetails
{

    private string nameField;

    private string sourceField;

    private string typeField;

    private string idField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Source
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sourceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sourceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEventEventTarget
{

    private string targetField;

    private string goalField;

    private ConfigEventEventTargetArg[] argsField;

    private bool usePreviousArgumentsField;

    private bool usePreviousArgumentsFieldSpecified;

    private ConfigEventEventTargetCallback callbackField;

    private ushort durationField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Target
    {
        get
        {
            return this.targetField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.targetField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Goal
    {
        get
        {
            return this.goalField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.goalField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Arg", IsNullable = false)]
    public ConfigEventEventTargetArg[] Args
    {
        get
        {
            return this.argsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.argsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool UsePreviousArguments
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usePreviousArgumentsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.usePreviousArgumentsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool UsePreviousArgumentsSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usePreviousArgumentsFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.usePreviousArgumentsFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ConfigEventEventTargetCallback Callback
    {
        get
        {
            return this.callbackField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.callbackField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return this.durationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.durationField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEventEventTargetArg
{

    private string keyField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this.keyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.keyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEventEventTargetCallback
{

    private string eventIDField;

    private byte delayField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string EventID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Delay
    {
        get
        {
            return this.delayField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.delayField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, for some reason the same XML at the top of this post is now generating the following:

'''

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEvent
{

    private ConfigEventEventDetails eventDetailsField;

    private ConfigEventEventTarget eventTargetField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ConfigEventEventDetails EventDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventDetailsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventDetailsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ConfigEventEventTarget EventTarget
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventTargetField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventTargetField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEventEventDetails
{

    private string nameField;

    private string sourceField;

    private string typeField;

    private string idField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Source
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sourceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sourceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEventEventTarget
{

    private object[] itemsField;

    private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Args", typeof(ConfigEventEventTargetArgs))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Callback", typeof(ConfigEventEventTargetCallback))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Duration", typeof(ushort))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Goal", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Target", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("UsePreviousArguments", typeof(bool))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEventEventTargetArgs
{

    private ConfigEventEventTargetArgsArg[] argField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Arg")]
    public ConfigEventEventTargetArgsArg[] Arg
    {
        get
        {
            return this.argField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.argField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEventEventTargetArgsArg
{

    private string keyField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this.keyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.keyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigEventEventTargetCallback
{

    private string eventIDField;

    private byte delayField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string EventID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Delay
    {
        get
        {
            return this.delayField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.delayField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema = false)]
public enum ItemsChoiceType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    Args,

    /// <remarks/>
    Callback,

    /// <remarks/>
    Duration,

    /// <remarks/>
    Goal,

    /// <remarks/>
    Target,

    /// <remarks/>
    UsePreviousArguments,
}
```

'''

Apologies for the poor code posting, I couldn't figure out how to get system tags to go into the code view so if someone could give a suggestion for that for the future, it would be appreciated.

For the problem itself though, I ideally need it to generate the code as it was before as it would take a considerable amount of time to refactor my application for this change. I'm also looking to understand what could of triggered the change and how to avoid it/potentially use it in the future.